# Нужны портабельные потоки с приоритетом для C++

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Понадобилась мне библиотека портабельных потоков для C++. Добрые люди посоветовали посмотреть в сторону pthread. Оказалось, что в pthread нет параметра "приоритет, на котором запускается поток".

В связи с этим возникают вопросы:

1. На каком приоритете запускаются потоки из pthread?
2. Есть ли в природе библиотека портабельных потоков с параметром "приоритет, на котором запускается поток"?

Comment: Портабельность и глубоко системно-зависимое понятие приоритета потока, боюсь, очень слабо совместимые понятия. Вам хочется странного. Какая ваша настоящая задача?

Comment: Раз так, вы должны спросить _кого следует_.

Comment: Задача проста. Есть приложение, ну там окна, меню, все как положено. И в этом приложении, в отдельном треде, запускается задача интерпретатора Basic, которая и делает всю работу. А само приложение только запускает и отображает результат работы интерпретатора Basic. Если эту задачу интерпретатора Basic запускать в треде на том же приоритете, что и само приложения с окнами, то задача интерпретатора Basic блокирует работу окон. Нужно запускать задачу интерпретатора Basic на пониженном приоритете. Для винды я сделал, но хотелось бы сделать портабельно.

Comment: Кого следует? А, это Вы про страну... Это просто шутка была.

Comment: Странно, на этом сайте у меня регулярно стирают "добрый день" в начале вопроса и "спасибо" в конце вопроса. Суровая русская модерация?

Comment: Приоритет потока это не системно-зависимое понятие. Во всяком случае не более системно-зависимое, чем сами потоки. Если есть поток, то есть и приоритет. Для ОС, где нет приоритета можно игнорировать параметр "приоритет".

Comment: Странно, что комментарии на этом сайте можно редактировать только в течении 5 минут. Приходится стирать комментарий и писать его заново, если надо что-то уточнить позже, чем через 5 минут.

Comment: Тем не менее, разработчики стандарта C++ с вашим мнением не согласны. Иначе они добавили бы приоритеты и в `std::thread`.

Comment: (Оффтопик: лишние слова типа «добрый день» считаются не относящимся к сути вопроса мусором и _не одобряются_. Редактирование комментария ограничено пятью минутами для того, чтобы исключить полностью меняющую смысл комментария правку, после чего ответы на этот комментарий начинают выглядеть глупо.)

Comment: И **очень** странно выглядит эффект, который вы описали. Интерпретатор бежит в соседнем потоке и никак не влияет на выполнение других потоков. Разве что он ест 100% ресурсов процессора. Что-то тут не так, вы копаете не туда. У меня в практике никогда работающий «на полную мощность» соседний поток не блокировал UI.

Comment: Интерпретатор не гоняет пустых циклов. Интерпретатор начинает выполняться в треде на том же приоритете, что и окна, и давит все своей активностью. Окнам просто не выделяется времени. Поэтому пришлось понизить приоритет треда для интерпретатора.

Comment: Да, именно интерпретатор (и вообще любой тред с одинаковым приоритетом с окнами) утягивает на себя все ресурсы процесса, так что даже мышь не бегает.

Comment: Очень странно. А при этом **другие** программы бегут нормально? Или останавливается вся система?

Comment: Все это написано на BCB 6.0. Кто не знает, там такая система, что в фоне нет ничего. Вся VCL это обработчики событий от окон и рисование окон. А для фона нет заготовки, так что фоновую задачу надо самому выносить в тред. Для тредов в VCL есть небольшой сервис - обертки над виндовскими тредами, но так, чисто декоративно.

Comment: Другие программы бегут нормально.

Comment: Значит, проблема не в том, что вы описываете. Для шедюлера нет разницы, какой именно поток запускать — ваш или чужого приложения. Бьюсь об заклад, у вас ошибка в синхронизации между потоками.

Comment: Ошибки синхронизации нет, хотя бы потому, что после понижения приоритете треда с интерпретатором все заработало.

Comment: На мой взгляд, то, что вставка `Sleep`'ов, понижение приоритета и тому подобные игры улучшают результат, свидетельствует как раз об ошибке в синхронизации. И как вы объясните, что интерпретатор странным образом мешает только вашему UI-потоку, а не другим потокам в системе?

Comment: Может быть есть какая-то секретная кнопка, чтобы указать шедулеру планировать поток. А может поток окон в VCL сам запускается на приоритете -1 к основному приоритету. Поэтому когда интерпретатор работал на основном приоритете, он давил окна. А когда я поставил интерпретатор на приоритете -1, то он стал вровень с окнами и шедулер их нормально разбросал во времени.

Comment: Sleep я не вставлял.

Comment: Возвращаясь к исходному вопросу - в любом случае для программиста нужен инструмент явного управления приоритетом потока. Странно, что таких потоков нет.

Comment: У вас одноядерный компьютер что ли?

Comment: Программа работала и на одно- и на многоядерных компьютерах.

Comment: Но на многоядерных при работе _двух_ потоков они никак не могут мешать друг другу (если они не связаны по коду)

Comment: Интересно, каким же образом в любом из \*nix Вы сможете в одном из потоков C++ запустить интерпретатор BASIC? Тащите с собой какую-то его библиотечную реализацию на C++? И Вы уверены, что она аккуратно подчищает всю память после каждого вызова. IMHO проще подвесить ее в отдельном процессе и общаться с ней.

Comment: Если реализация интерпретатора не аккуратно подчищает память, то она и в отдельном процессе повиснет и все приложение упадет, так же, как и при запуске интерпретатора в отдельном потоке. Так что тут разницы нет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Кроссплатформенные потоки это `std::thread`. С каких пор pthreads стали «портабельными», мне не ясно, pthread это p[OSIX]thread. Выставить приоритет с помощью `std::thread` нельзя, но можно получить `std::thread::native_handle`, с которым далее работать с помощью API той или иной ОС.

<s>Я мало знаком с Linux, но беглый осмотр показал, что как такового понятия приоритета там нет, поэтому говорить о кросс-платформенном решении изменения приоритета нельзя.</s>
В Linux есть niceness, но как это значение унифицировать с приоритетами из Windows — непонятно. Поэтому весьма вероятно, что никто не стал заниматься кроссплатформенной реализацией функционала, который необходим паре процентов всего софта.

Comment: Приоритеты потоков в linux есть, только в большинстве случаев они не нужны

Comment: @sercxjo: Именно так. Необходимость управлять приоритетами потоков — признак ошибки в дизайне программы.

Comment: Ну почему же признак ошибки? Если поток библиотечный поток работает на каком-то приоритете, то свой поток надо уметь двигать по приоритетам.

Comment: @VladD, чаще всего, вероятно, — да. Но не всегда. Софт разный бывает и требования тоже.